# Nulo no corpo da requisição

Tags: java, json, api, rest

Utilizo em um projeto DTOs para entrada e saídas de dados.
Na requisição estou enviando um objeto do tipo ProductModel com **todas as propriedades**, mas o objeto retornado do controlador contém todas as **propriedades nulas**.

A assinatura do método está correta:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public ProductModel adicionarPorSku(@RequestBody ProductModel productModel)
```

O corpo que estou enviando:

```
{
"sku": 43264,
"name": "L'Oréal Professionnel Expert Absolut Repair Cortex Lipidium - Máscara de Reconstrução 500g",
"inventory": {
    "quantity": 15,
    "warehouses": [
        {
            "locality": "SP",
            "quantity": 12,
            "type": "ECOMMERCE"
        },
        {
            "locality": "MOEMA",
            "quantity": 3,
            "type": "PHYSICAL_STORE"
        }
    ]}}
```

E assim estão as classes do meu Representation Model:

```
    public class ProductModel {

    @NotNull
    private Long sku;
    
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private InventoryModel inventory;
    
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Boolean isMarkeatable;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class InventoryModel {
    
    @PositiveOrZero
    private Long quantity;
    
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private List<WarehouseModel> warehouses;
    
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class WarehouseModel {

    @NotBlank
    private String locality;

    @NotNull
    private Long quantity;

    @NotBlank
    private String type;

}


Já tentei enviar objetos de outros tipos, e tudo funcionou normalmente, mas como esse tipo (ProductModel) foi instanciado tudo com valor null.
```

Answer (score -3):

A sua classe ProductModel está sem os Getters e Setter, assim o objeto não consegue criar os campos do objeto. Tente colocar um @Data em cima da classe.